# Unable to send a proxy object to Server

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I have a value proxy object in my client side which I have created using a Request Context. I use the same request context to save that object. Till here its fine.

Now there is a new requirement where I need to send the same object to the server (for different purpose) to the server before the actual save in the flow. How can I do that?

I tried to create a new request context and then send object with that, but I got an error saying thats not allowed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to duplicate/clone it. As it's a `ValueProxy` it shouldn't be a problem. The *issue* is that there's [no easy and clean way to *clone* a proxy](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5794).

The cleanest solution is to use [`AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/shared/AutoBeanUtils.html#getAutoBean%28U%29) and then an [`AutoBeanVisitor`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/shared/AutoBean.html#accept%28com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.AutoBeanVisitor%29) to visit each property and set it on another proxy.

An easier way is to [serialize the proxy into a `ProxyStore`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/RequestFactory.html#getSerializer%28com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.ProxyStore%29) and deserialize it, which will create a distinct proxy.